# Overlapping Next Item in Vertical FlatList - React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to overlap items in a FlatList.

This flatlist basically loads all the widgets of my app. It's a server driven UI. The

**Profile widget on top, needs to overlap the Image widget below it.**

I'll attach some screenshots which will better explain the problem:

**What I have currently**

[image]

**What I want to achieve**
[image]

**What's happening**
[image]

**I tried adding zIndex & elevation, but they didn't work.**

The circle should come on top of the image, but if I make it absolutely positioned, it's coming behind the image.

All the widgets are in separate files and are functional components. They're being loaded in a FlatList.

Let me know if you need more information, will be happy to add.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You have have to use position:'absolute' and put the circle element as the last element of the elements list so it comes to top.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Here's the code for the same:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry, FlatList,
  StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert,Image
} from 'react-native';

export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#000",
        }}/>
    );
  };
  //handling onPress action  
  getListViewItem = (item) => {
    Alert.alert(item.key);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            { key: 'Android' }, { key: 'iOS' }, { key: 'Java' }, { key: 'Swift' },
            { key: 'Php' }, { key: 'Hadoop' }, { key: 'Sap' },
            { key: 'Python' }, { key: 'Ajax' }, { key: 'C++' },
            { key: 'Ruby' }, { key: 'Rails' }, { key: '.Net' },
            { key: 'Perl' }, { key: 'Sap' }, { key: 'Python' },
            { key: 'Ajax' }, { key: 'C++' }, { key: 'Ruby' },
            { key: 'Rails' }, { key: '.Net' }, { key: 'Perl' }
          ]}
          renderItem={({}) =>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', height:250, marginBottom:10}}>
            <Image source={require('./img/image1.jpg')} style={{ height:250,}}/>
          </View>
            }
        />
        <View style={{ margin: 10, position: 'absolute' }}>
          <View style={{
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            borderRadius: 10, height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 100 / 2
          }}></View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
})


AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlatListBasics);
```

Comment: The circle element is not something outside the flatlist. It's a flatlist item itself. Cannot render it outside the flatlist.

Comment: As you mention "Profile widget on top, needs to overlap the Image widget below it." You no where mentioned that element is part of flat-list. Please ask a proper question with clarifying what exactly you need as an output.

Comment: I said:

This flatlist basically loads all the widgets of my app. It's a server driven UI. The
Profile widget on top, needs to overlap the Image widget below it.

I explicitly said Profile WIDGET. Please read the question carefully.